# How to Interface STM32F302R8 with ADS1256 using spi communication?

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f4discovery, nucleo, interfacing

I've tried interfacing the Nucleo-F302R8 and the High precision AD/DA waveshare board using SPI communication. While do so I'm unable to transmit or receive data. I've used spi3 for communication and gave a i/o for chip select pin. the spi_clk pin is not generating any clock pulse. I tried debugging spi through loop back and found that reception is happening at mosi pin but the again the clock is empty (checked using digital oscilloscope. I'm new to this environment and in need of great help. I've shared snippet my code below.
Spi configuration: 2lines, 8bit, polarity low, phase 1edge, msb first

```
void adc_write(uint8_t address, uint8_t value)
{
uint8_t data[3];
data[0] = 0x50|address;
data[1] = 0x01;
data[2] = value;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3, data,receive, 3, 50);
//DWT_Delay(10);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void adc_write_command(uint8_t command)
{
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3,&command,receive,1,50);
  //DWT_Delay(10);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

}

int adc_read()
{
uint8_t datacon;
uint32_t convert = 0x00;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
adc_write_command(0x01); //read

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3,0x00,&datacon,1,50);
convert |= datacon;
convert<<=8;
}

//DWT_Delay(10);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
return convert;
}

float volt(uint32_t data2)
{
float v;
 v =(float) data2*0.000000596046; // 8388607 = +5.000v reference voltage
return v;
}


void adc_read_regis(uint8_t address1)
{
uint8_t data1[3];
data1[0] = 0x50|address1;
data1[1] = 0x01;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3, data1,receive, 2, 50);
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3,0x00, &data1[2],1,50);
//DWT_Delay(10);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void adc_reset()
{
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_Delay(1);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void adc_init()
{
adc_write(0x00, 0x03); //status
adc_write(0x02, 0x20); //adcon
adc_write(0x03, 0x82); //drate 100sps
adc_read_regis(0x00); //verification
adc_write_command(0xF0); //selfcab of adc
adc_write(0x01, 0x0F); //mux for channel 0 positive
adc_write_command(0xFC); //sync
adc_write_command(0x00); //wake up
HAL_Delay(500);

}

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
* @brief The application entry point.
* @retval int
*/
int main(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

uint32_t adc_data_ch0, adc_data_ch1;
float voltage_ch0, voltage_ch1;

/* USER CODE END 1 */


/* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

/* USER CODE END Init */

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

/* USER CODE END SysInit */

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_SPI3_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 MX_GPIO_Init();
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
 adc_reset();
 HAL_Delay(500);
 MX_SPI3_Init();
 HAL_Delay(500);
 adc_write_command(0xFE); //reset to power up values
 adc_write_command(0xFC); //sync
 adc_write_command(0x00); //wake up
 //DWT_Delay(10);
 adc_init();
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); //confirm configuration
 MX_USART2_UART_Init();

/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1)
{
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
 while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(DRDY_GPIO_Port,DRDY_Pin));
 adc_write(0x01, 0x1F); //mux for ch1 positive channel
 adc_write_command(0xFC); //sync
 adc_write_command(0x00); //wake up
 adc_data_ch0 = adc_read();
 voltage_ch0 = volt(adc_data_ch0);
 HAL_Delay(100);
 while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(DRDY_GPIO_Port,DRDY_Pin));
 adc_write(0x01, 0x0F); //mux for ch0 positive channel
 adc_write_command(0xFC); //sync
 adc_write_command(0x00); //wake up
 adc_data_ch1 = adc_read();
 voltage_ch1 = volt(adc_data_ch1);
 //frequency_in_ch1 = freq(voltage_in_ch1);

 HAL_Delay(100);

 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

}
 /* USER CODE END WHILE */

 /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

/* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: You should add the code of function `MX_SPI3_Init`

Comment: Also, I think the STM32 is able to manage the NSS signal automatically, you shouldn't have to manage it by toggling a GPIO.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I've added the MX_SPI3_INIT in my code. I've just shared the snippet of my code.  I didnt use the nss pin instead I went with a gpio port for chip_select. I've also mentioned my spi_init configuration above. Can you exactly pin point where the problem actually is or with little extra specifications. It would be more helpful for my development.

Comment: "I've added the MX_SPI3_INIT in my code" sorry but I dont't think you did. i'm talking about the implementation of the function. Also you are calling this function twice (even if it's probably not the root cause). if the STM32 is the Master and you see it sending data (on MOSI, as you say), I don't see why the clock is not moving. the setup if SPI can be difficult but as far as I know a Master will always send the clock signal together with the data.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean clock problem is sorted out as of now. But the communication is not proper as in I'm writing a register in adc and when i try to read it back again it shows some different values. I have noticed that i made the initiation twice and changed it correctly. Can i get a correct for this communication.I want to get digital data from analog input channel 0 from the adc board. I really don't know where the problem is.

Comment: I try to help you but you don't answer the questions, neither try to apply what I suggest.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I'm really sorry if I misunderstood you. I'm open to all suggestions and will apply the same for sure. Sorry!